# How to override the menu_tree without affecting the admin menus

Tags: theming, routes

I've worked out how to override `theme_menu_tree()` using this code in template.php.

```
function myTheme_menu_tree($variables) {
  return '<nav class="menu">' . $variables['tree'] . '</nav>';
}
```

However, I've noticed that this is affecting other menus as well.

How do I target only non-admin menus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [theme_menu_tree__MENU_NAME()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_tree/7).

Answer (score 0):

#### page.tpl.php

```
// for admin menu
<?php print '<ul id="nav-admin" class="menu clearfix">'.menu_tree('navigation').'</ul>';?>

// for primary menu
 <?php print  '<ul id="nav-primary" class="menu clearfix">' . menu_tree('primary-links').'</ul>'; ?>

// for secondary menu
 <?php print  '<ul id="nav-secondary" class="menu clearfix">' . menu_tree('secondary-links').'</ul>'; ?>
```

#### template.php

```
function yourthemename_menu_tree($tree) {
  return $tree;
}
```